# Itunes Connect - Cannot reject binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

With the new Itunes Connect web UI (Oct 15), I can no longer find a way to reject the binary once the status has changed to **waiting for review**.

I checked the Apple docs and it seems to be out-of-date, as they refer to the **remove this version from review** link, which is no longer there.

All the similar threads on this forum date more than one year ago and refer to the old UI.

Has anyone managed to find it?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: The *remove this version from review* banner has reappeared.

Comment: Hey Daniel! I was having the same issue, and it resolved itself after waiting about an hour. Just kept refreshing the page... Sigh.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like a bug of itunesconnect in new UI.
I have tried these solutions:

1. logout and login.
2. clear safari history.
3. upload a new version binary.

But none helps me.

[image]

---

### EDIT:

Yesterday I submitted the bug on Bug Reporter.

[image]

Today the reject button came back! As @Jackson suspected, they did not respond, but they did something. I suspect they just temporarily do something for the one who submit bug, but have not fixed the issue. So, you should have a try if you don't want to wait. Submit a bug to them on Bug Reporter!

[image]

Comment: I've added images to my post. I think the issue is you don't have that permission. Check your role in iTunes connect. I think it may be "Technical"

Comment: I tried "Technical" and "Manager". None works. I added screenshots to my post.

Comment: @MidhunMP, we are not seeing it. It is a real issue. I am an agent with all the possible permissions. Opened a ticket with Apple. Will let you know when it gets resolved.

Comment: @DanielShimshoni: Thanks for the info, glad to know more about the, please let me know if it is fixed. FYI : My role is admin.

Comment: I tried all of those. I cleared browsing history, logged off, rebooted, logged back on, submitted a new binary (which is through the processing stage) and I still can't reject the binary that is "waiting for review". I also tried on a Windows machine which has no browsing history with my ITC account and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: @JohnSlegers JAL e4c5    Sorry guys! Yesterday I don't have enough reputation to comment. And this is a reduplicate question. So, this is the only way to say "I have the same problem" .

Answer (score 4):

Date : 30 June 2016 , Today

Link to reject binary disappears from the app iTunesConnect Website.

Workaround :

Download iTunes Connect application in iphone and reject the binary from their.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the link is there. You can find that link by the following steps.

1. Log In to iTunes connect
2. Go to My Apps section
3. Choose your app from there
4. Make sure you are in AppStore section in that page
5. In the left hand side, find the iOS App section and choose the waiting for review item
6. Now you will see the `remove this version from review` on top of that page as a banner
7. Click on that link

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 4, 5, 6]

Apple introduced more roles in the iTunes Connect. I think you are getting issues because of that. Check your role in iTunes connect.

Comment: That link doesn't exist for me, and I don't think it exists for the author of this post either.

Comment: @Jackson: I've added images as well. This is what I'm getting in my iTunes connect account.

Comment: I am glad it shows up for you. It does not show up for me, or for many other users, hence my question.

Comment: Thanks for posting the image in more detail but the part that says "to submit a new build you must remove this version from review" is precisely what DOES NOT appear for many of us. It used to appear, as I just rejected a binary a few days ago but as of yesterday I don't see it anymore, and my role hasn't changed (I'm the only member of my team).

Comment: As promised, I am keeping you posted.

It seems to be an Apple bug. I contacted Apple and they escalated it. The link now re-appeared and I was able to reject the binary and resubmit.

Thanks for all your answers- they helped me to identify the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I just checked and the "remove this version from review" banner has magically reappeared at the top of the screen in iTunes connect. I guess it was just a temporary issue which Apple did not acknowledge, and it took several days for them to fix it. I hope the problem is solved for you too!

Originally I had the same problem. There should have been some text at the top of the iTunes connect page for the current version waiting for review that says "remove this version from review" as a sort of banner but I didn't see for about 24 hours.
[image]

Comment: I'm getting this same issue. I posted basically the same screenshot in a question a few hours ago. Glad to know it's not just me.

Comment: I've added images to my post. I think the issue is you don't have that permission. Check your role in iTunes connect. I think it may be "Technical"

Comment: I am an agent and am not getting the link. I have contacted Apple and they have escalated the issue. No resolution yet.

Comment: I am the only person on my dev team so I have all roles. I could always reject binaries in the past but this time I don't have the option. Thanks for contacting Apple. I have contacted them but did not hear back yet. Please post any updates you get here. I will do the same.

Comment: I have also contacted Apple twice about this today - the button came back for me earlier, but then i had to resubmit another binary and by then it was gone again.

Comment: @Jackson    Mine is still missing 

Comment: @ShannonChou I wonder if me contacting Apple resulted in it getting fixed? They didn't respond but maybe someone at Apple did something.

Comment: @Jackson   Yesterday I submitted the bug to Apple on Bug Reporter. Today the reject button magically came back too, as you suspected!!

Comment: @ShannonChou funny because Apple emailed me today asking me how to reproduce the problem. The funny thing was it was already fixed so I couldn't show them how to reproduce it!

Comment: @Jackson  I guess they have not fixed it. Just someone temporarily do something for the one who submit a bug. It's not official act. Maybe someone don't want his boss know he made a serious bug.   haha!!!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the banner as well, but as soon as I selected the old version from the left tab and the "Waiting for Review" version again, the banner reappeared.